# Automatic magnifying software or Chrome Extension

Tags: chrome, automation, user-interface, windows-10

I want to automatically zoom to a preset size whenever i'm viewing text. Ideally this would work with my programs as well.

I'm using Chrome on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Zoom text only](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/zoom%20text%20only) and [Zoom](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/zoom/lajondecmobodlejlcjllhojikagldgd) extensions let's you save your zoom level per website.

**Zoom text only** still breaks pages if you magnify too much, and **Zoom** can require scrolling from side to side and may break images. Used together, they fight crime!

Answer (score 2):

I believe windows has a built-in software called [magnifier](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-PH/windows-xp/help/turn-on-magnifier) or if you want you can install [magnifier extension for chrome](https://www.google.com.ph/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=chrome%20extensions%20magnifier) which is more convenient i think. And also you can zoom in and zoom out to your web browsers view via using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> key and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd> in windows.